# Deployment on an IIS Server 2016 - HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, .net-6.0

I am trying to deploy an asp.net Core app on my server IIS 2016 64 bit but it's not working. I get an HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET COre app failed to start :

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start Common solutions
> to this issue:

The app failed to start

The app started but then stopped

The app started but threw an exception during startup

**Troubleshooting steps:**

Check the system event log for error messages

Enable logging the application process' stdout messages

Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265

The authentication solution to my app is by **SSO Windows**.
I worked on C# 10, .Net 6.00 on Visual Studio 2022.
When I launch it on my computer directly, no error message it is working perfectly !

I have try to change the debug way OutOfProcess but it's not working.
I have try to add in my Program.cs file :

```
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(options =>
{
    options.SourceName = "Ged&Docs";
});
```

But it's not working. I have try to add also :

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
```

But it's not working.

I can not change the server and I can not deploy it on Azure.

Have you an idea ? Can you help me to deploy my solution ?

Thank you so much !!

Comment: `SSO Windows` means windows authentication? We'd better to try to collect the error messages so that we could locate the issue. Let's also take a look at the application event view not only the system event view. By the way, I also want to check if your running environment is working well, let's create a new .net 6 mvc project and host it in the win server IIS, let's see if it worked well. If the newly created project worked well after being published to IIS, then we could focus on the problematic app and related configuration then.

Comment: Yes it is windows authentication. We are thinking that maybe the app be in http not in https could be the solution. We are trying to add SSL certificate to the IIS server try to fix it.

Comment: Hi ! yes it is windows authentication. The problem is I don't have any other error message that Http Error 500.30. How can I check if my running environnement is working well ?
For information, I have already deploy the app without the SSO Windows and everything is working fine. 
So, I think that the problem is because my app is in http not in https. I am trying to add SSL Certificate to the IIS Server to change it. Maybe it's the solution

Comment: yes I agree with you, and you might try to add SSL and see if https was the solution.